# Probability interpretation when spectrum not fully discrete or continuous

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider the delta well. You have a bound state and scattering states.

Can I get a normalizable solution to the schrodinger equation that is some sort of a combination of the bound state and continuous states (maybe of the form *bound state wave function* + *fourier integral for scattered states*)?

Since even the bound state can be written as a linear combo of the scattered states, does this mean I can't interpret the fourier inverse transform as a probability density? Because if I could, then that would imply the bound state can give a range of positive energies, which makes no sense.

In general, can I get normalizable solutions to the schrodinger equation that are combos of bound states and scattered states? What is the probability interpretation then?

Note, the delta well has a half discrete/ half continous spectrum, which is where the issue of interpretation arises. (for discrete, I have orthonormality that explains interpretation and for totally continuous, I have dirac orthonormality).

Comment: Can someone put a bounty on this please? I don't have enough points to do that, and my only other option is to make this a functional analysis question and ask on mathstackexchange.